# jquery autocomplete dynamic source from data attribute

Tags: jquery-ui, autocomplete, coffeescript

There is few topics on the same subject, but non completely satisfied me!

I want to define the source of my autocomplete through a data attribute, like so:

```
<input data-behaviour='autocomplete' data-source='/path/to/source'>
```

I'm unable to get it programmatically through the `source` method:

```
$ ->
  $('[data-behaviour~=autocomplete]').autocomplete
    source: (req, resp) ->
      return $(this).data('source')
```

[Here](http://codepen.io/jobwat/pen/kjoEm) is a non-working snippet to play with...

EDIT: a workaround I've found is to set it through the `create` method:

```
$ ->
  $('[data-behaviour~=autocomplete]').autocomplete
    create: (event, ui) ->
      $(this).autocomplete( "option", "source", $(this).data('source') )
```

Check this [snippet](http://codepen.io/jobwat/pen/FawAx)

But I don't really like this approach, I'm pretty sure better can be done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with coffeescript; the jQuery UI automplete have a `source` option that allow you to make some custom stuff; in your case you can use the third option (function) using `request` and setting the `response` parameter.

> Function: The third variation, a callback, provides the most
>   flexibility and can be used to connect any data source to
>   Autocomplete. The callback gets two arguments: A request object, with
>   a single term property, which refers to the value currently in the
>   text input. For example, if the user enters "new yo" in a city field,
>   the Autocomplete term will equal "new yo". A response callback, which
>   expects a single argument: the data to suggest to the user. This data
>   should be filtered based on the provided term, and can be in any of
>   the formats described above for simple local data. It's important when
>   providing a custom source callback to handle errors during the
>   request. You must always call the response callback even if you
>   encounter an error. This ensures that the widget always has the
>   correct state. When filtering data locally, you can make use of the
>   built-in $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex function. It'll take a single
>   string argument and escape all regex characters, making the result
>   safe to pass to new RegExp().

Ref: http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source

Code:

```
$ ->
  thisEl = $('[data-behaviour~=autocomplete]');
  $('[data-behaviour~=autocomplete]').autocomplete
    source: (req, resp) ->
      resp(thisEl.data('source'));
```

Is only an example you have to implement the filtering pattern.

Demo: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gjmHn